# How can I use different pagination class per action in Django?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using Viewsets. For example, to use different serializer per action I can override `get_serializer_class()` method. But what about pagination class? Is there any way to set pagination class other than `pagination_class = <my pagination class>`? I think this is not good as it will change the `pagination_class` for all the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the Pagination class with your own.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class PageNumberPaginationDataOnly(PageNumberPagination):
    # Set any other options you want here like page_size

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        # implement your logic
        return Response(data)
```